# Search Room Availability

Tags: mysql, sql, database

These are my tables:

`Room` (roomId, roomName, roomTypeId, roomStatus)

`RoomType` (roomTypeId, roomTypeName, roomTypeDesc, roomTypePrice)

`ReservationRoom` (reservationId, roomId,checkInDate, checkOutDate, totalStay)

I receive three parameter from user (check in date, check out date, quantity)to search the available room type that can be reserve into a grid view.

This is my sql that show the available roomtype for reserve.

```
SELECT rt.roomTypeName, rt.roomTypePrice, count(*) as quantity 
FROM Room r,
     RoomType rt 
WHERE roomStatus = 'Online'
  AND r.roomTypeId = rt.roomTypeId 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ReservationRoom b
                  WHERE b.roomId = r.roomId 
                    AND (@CheckInDate BETWEEN b.checkInDate AND b.checkOutDate 
                         OR @CheckOutDate BETWEEN b.checkInDate AND b.checkOutDate 
                         OR (@CheckInDate<= b.checkInDate AND @CheckOutDate >= b.checkOutDate)))
group by rt.roomTypeName, rt.roomTypePrice
Having COUNT(*) >= @quantity";
```

It works quite well. But it got problem when my ReservationRoom table already have a record which is checkindate (1/11/2015) and check out date (2/11/2015) made by guest A for roomtypeA.

When a guest B search for room on check in date is(2/11/2015) and check out date is(3/11/2015).it will still show the roomtypeA is not available. But it should be available because the guest A already check out on 2/11. so is there any way to let user B reserve the roomtype in this situation?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert from type DATE columns to [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) columns, and then compare specific times of day (i.e., your specific check-out time, such as 11am).

Or, convert all times to [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), and then you will have simpler greater-than / less-than comparisons altogether, since it's just an integer.

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `str_to_date` or `cast` because you must need to convert your type as `DATE`

```
cast(str_to_date('1/11/2015','%d/%m/%Y')as date)
```

or

```
cast(str_to_date(checkindate,'%d/%m/%Y')as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using BETWEEN as it is inclusive of the two dates - see the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) material